# How to disagnose why React Native app crashes only on Android for release variant

Tags: android, react-native, build

I can run my app in an Android simulator, downloaded from the app store to Apple devices, but not in any combination of Android and a release variant. Running `.\gradlew build` builds the app with no errors but after downloading the app from the internal testing branch it fails to even show the splash screen. Installing the app to a virtual device using `npx react-native run-android --variant=release` will yield the same result: the app installs without complaint but crashes after flashing a black screen for about a quarter second.

Here is my stack info:

```
    > npx react-native info
info Fetching system and libraries information...
System:
    OS: Windows 10 10.0.19043
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz
    Memory: 4.92 GB / 15.89 GB
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.14.2 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    Yarn: 1.19.1 - ~\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.CMD
    npm: 8.1.4 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
    Watchman: Not Found
  SDKs:
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 28, 29, 30, 31, 32
      Build Tools: 29.0.2, 30.0.0, 30.0.1, 30.0.2, 30.0.3, 31.0.0, 32.0.0, 32.1.0
      System Images: android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-30 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-30 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom
      Android NDK: 22.1.7171670
    Windows SDK:
      AllowAllTrustedApps: Disabled
      Versions: 10.0.17763.0, 10.0.18362.0
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: AI-213.7172.25.2113.9123335
    Visual Studio: 15.9.28307.2019 (Visual Studio Professional 2017), 16.4.29806.167 (Visual Studio Community 2019), 17.2.32630.192 (Visual Studio Community 2022)
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.12 - C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot\bin\javac.EXE
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 18.1.0 => 18.1.0
    react-native: 0.70.4 => 0.70.4
    react-native-windows: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

I haven't made any changes to the files in Android or startup files since a known working copy. I have tried:

- uninstalling and installing Android Studio
- `npx react-native doctor`
- rolled back my `index.js` file just in case
- `.\gradlew clean`
- restart computer

Is there any way to diagnose the problem or is there any hint of a solution?

==== REVISIT ====

I noticed two locations for Android Studio, `C:\Program Files\Android\` and `AppData\Local\Android\`. I removed the Android Studio in both locations while now only `C:\Program Files` has Android Studio after a reinstall and now I can no longer get the app to build. Running any `react-native` command now yields the same result:

```
> npx react-native run-android variant=release
error Failed to load configuration of your project.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
adb logcat
```

This doesn't answer your question entirely since you're using an emulator, but if you can get your hands on an android device, this will solve your problem.

In a separate terminal window, run the above command. It's super verbose, but you'll be able to see all your logs there. Search through the mass of code, and somewhere there will be an accurate report of the cause for the crash. It's the only useful tool I've found for production specific crashes.

Comment: You weren't kidding when you said it's super verbose - infinite maybe.

Comment: Yea lol it's nuts. Sorry its not the best solution, but it's something. I usually throw in some console logs in the app entry file (usually your app.jsx or index.jsx) and use it as marker for the general area I should start searching.